# Lgged in user details not changing

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

So when I run my app and I log in, the name and email of the current user is shown in the navigation drawer, but when I sign out and log in with another user, the details remain the same of the previous user, the data is being retrieved from the database, but its not changing when the next user logs in.

I have tried to check if the user exists by using `getUid`. but whenever I use that piece of code anywhere, it gives me a null pointer exception. How do I resolve this?

Much appreciated

Code as follows:

```
  public void pushToNavHeader(){

    mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mRef.child("Users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                        for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
                            View v = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
                            TextView nName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                            TextView nEmail = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);

                            nName.setText("");
                            nEmail.setText("");


                            Users user = data.getValue(Users.class);
                            name = user.getName();
                            email = user.getEmail();

                            nName.setText(name);
                            nEmail.setText(email);
                        }
                    }

                }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

[Firebase database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyF0G.png)

```
    {
  "Users" : 
{
    "7wWFORCN8NMHoihSJeGs7pBWakt1" : 
{
      "email" : "ben@gmail.com",
      "name" : "ben"
    },
    "FYcpquwFVfTrIPsXda82BSb2vpr1" : 
{
      "email" : "neesan@gmail.com",
      "name" : "neesan"
    }
  }
}
```

Users Class

```
public class Users {

    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String password;

        public Users(){
        }

        public String getName(){
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name){
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getEmail(){
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email){
            this.email = email;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please paste your code as text. Never ever use a screenshot for your code: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors Please also consider to read [ask] or take the [tour]

Comment: Better indeed. Cleaning up comments.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Firebase Authentication, the correct way to detect that the logged in user has changed is `FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener` as described in the "Listen for auth state" section of the Authentication docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start/

The docs show example snippets that should help, but for a more complete example check out [AnonymousAuthActivity.java](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/AnonymousAuthActivity.java#L65-L80).

Listening to the "Users" section of your database will only notify you when the "Users" section of your database is updated, which won't help you update the app when a different user logs in.